# Поиск элемента из массива

Tags: jquery

Задача такая: нужно из элемента формы получить все текстовые поля и поменять значение `value` у конкретного элемента, допустим у третьего .

```
$('.reg:text'); // получи доступ ко всем элементам text из класса reg
```

Answer (score 3):

Перебор:

```
$('yourForm').children('input:text').each(function (index) {
    //перебор всех элементов
    if (index == 2) { //третий элемент, так как у первого index==0
        //исполняем, например:
        $(this).val('newVal');
        //назначили новый value третьему элементу
    }
});
```

Мгновенный доступ:

```
$('yourForm').children('input:text').eq(2).val('newVal'); //исполняем. Назначили новый value третьему элементу.
```

Comment: не могу понять как работает 1 способ и 2 
//1
$('.yourForm').children('input:text').each(function(index, element) {
 if (index == 0)
 {
  element.val('asd'); 
 }
});
//2
$('.yourForm').children('input:text').eq(1).val('asd')

Comment: В первом способе функция each проходится просто по всем элементам, которые есть в выборке input:text этой формы. Параметр индекс(назовите его как угодно) - это порядковый номер элемента в массиве выборки. Когда мы доходим до нужного(нужных) индекса(индексов), мы можем делать с ним что мы хотели. Ссылка на элемент в данной конструкции - $(this)  

Во втором случае, мы просто получаем ссылку на элемент. Удобно, когда обрабатываемых элементов мало.  

пример использования сейчас добавлю.

Comment: Не получается может я что то не так сделал ?
$('.yourForm').children('input:text').each(function(index) {
 if (index == 0)
 {
  $(this).val('123');
 }
});

Comment: $('.yourForm')// Тут точно правильный селектор для формы?

Comment: Селектор формы правильный сам не пойму в чем траблы